# Domain Proxy issue in grails

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I am having problems accessing .setId() on my domain objects. Here is how the troubled code:

Service:

```
ftmBusinessPartner = FtmBusinessPartner.get(seqId)
    if(!ftmBusinessPartner){
        ftmBusinessPartner = new FtmBusinessPartner()
        ftmBusinessPartner.id = seqId
    }
```

DOMINAIN:

```
class FtmBusinessPartner {
static auditable = true
String shortName
// Relation
BusinessPartner businessPartner

private static final String SQL_FORMAT_STRING = "INSERT INTO FTM_BUSINESS_PARTNER (ID, VERSION, BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID, SHORT_NAME) values (%1\$d, %2\$d, %3\$d, '%4\$s');"

static mapping = {
     table 'FTM_BUSINESS_PARTNER'
     businessPartner column:'BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID'
     shortName column:'SHORT_NAME'
     sort businessPartner:'asc'
     if(EnviromentUtil.getEnv().equals(FtmConstants.EB2B_DEVL)){
         id column:'ID', generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'FTM_BUSINESS_PARTNER_SEQ']
     }
     else{
         id column:'ID', generator:'assigned'
     }
}

static constraints = {
    shortName(size: 1..10, blank: false, nullable:false)
    businessPartner(nullable: false, lazy:false)
    id(nullable:false)
}
```

On first run my meta class is: 
class com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmBusinessPartner_$$_javassist_34
this always failed with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmBusinessPartner
at com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmBusinessPartner_$$_javassist_34$setId.call(Unknown Source)
at com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.XmlPromotionService.ftmBusinessPartnerXmlInit(XmlPromotionService.groovy:221)
at com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.XmlPromotionService$ftmBusinessPartnerXmlInit.call(Unknown Source)
at com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmFeedService.readXml(FtmFeedService.groovy:185)
at com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmFeedService$readXml.call(Unknown Source)
at com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmFeedController$_closure12.doCall(FtmFeedController.groovy:268)
at com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmFeedController$_closure12.doCall(FtmFeedController.groovy)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

If I kill the JVM and rerun i get this for my metaClass and it runs just fine:

```
class com.nf.eb2b.ftm.dataEntry.FtmBusinessPartner
```

So my question here is why do i get a proxy on first JVM but the actual domain on the second? Is there a way to force my Domain to not be a proxy on the new FtmBusinessPartner() call?
Note:
I have tried `GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy(ftmBusinessPartner)` with no success.

Comment: Also worth noting, this is NOT in devl. So the ID is assigned.

Comment: seqId is a String or Long? If this a String, it will not complain in the `get()` because the method can handle it, but it will give you errors in manually assignments.

Comment: It is a long. It will work fine on second running of the JVM. Then when I switch to point at another DB (identical for testing purpose) it fails again.

Comment: Try `id column: 'ID', bindable: true, generator: 'assigned'` and `new FtmBusinessPartner(id: seqId)`

Comment: Just tried, failed. Grails doesn't allow a map constructor set the ID field. After the constructor call, id remained null.

Comment: hmmm the bindable should do it...

Comment: Everything i've read has said that you can not set and ID through a map constructor. Also even in the even that the ID did set, it's still a proxy. Not shown here, late in the code i set more fields in the domain. That is why i really dont care about setting the ID to say, i care about not getting a proxy or being able to convert that proxy into an instance of the actual domain.